# Wireless keyboard malfunction seems to be in Wn 7

Tags: wireless-keyboard

I'm using a Microsoft Arc wireless keyboard with Windows 7.

The problem: if I let the keyboard sit idle for a few minutes and then start typing, no characters appear on the screen. But then, after a few moments, the keyboard comes to life and the computer accepts what I type.

The first characters I typed (when the keyboard was dead) do not appear, so they haven't been buffered.

When I attach a different MS Arc wireless KB to the computer, the problem still happens. But it does not happen on other computers in the office, even when I attach the KB that first showed the problem. So this problem is in the system, somehow.

When I connect a wired (USB) keyboard to computer A, the problem does not appear. So it happens only with the wireless (I don't have any other wireless brands to try, just the MS Arc).

I've tried replacing the batteries.

The only things I could find on Google said something about "Keyboard Hooks timeout". They suggested adding a timeout value to the registry. I tried that with no joy.

Has anyone encountered this? What could be the cause?

Comment: Seems as if on your PC the wireless transceiver is powering down after some time, and then takes time to power back up and restore the connection, during which time of course the keyboard is unresponsive. Check the driver software as well as device settings in Device Manager for power saving options.

Answer (score 0):

Battery-powered wireless devices go to sleep when not in use, it takes them a while to wake up (and reconnect). Happens with all my wireless mice.

Comment: We have several wireless keyboards in the office. This is the only one that has this behavior. --  Also, when we moved to another office, the problem disappeared.